# Making requests with Typhoeus, certain URLs consistently return empty '400' responses

Tags: ruby, http, curl, libcurl, typhoeus

Certain URLs always return an empty HTTP 400 response (many other URLs work fine). Example:

```
1.9.3p0 :002 > e = Typhoeus::Easy.new

e.url = "http://us.asos.com/NW3/NW3-Highgate-Seersucker-Pinafore-Dress/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=1988231&cid=8799&sh=0&pge=0&pgesize=20&sort=-1&clr=Navy%252fivory&r=2"

1.9.3p0 :004 > e.perform => 400

1.9.3p0 :005 > y e
--- !ruby/object:Typhoeus::Easy 
curl_return_code: 0
headers: {}

method: :get
response_body: ""
response_header: |
  HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
  Content-Type: text/html
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
  Content-Length: 0
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Date: Mon, 07 May 2012 19:35:28 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive

ssl_version: :default
url: http://us.asos.com/NW3/NW3-Highgate-Seersucker-Pinafore-Dress/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=1988231&cid=8799&sh=0&pge=0&pgesize=20&sort=-1&clr=Navy%252fivory&r=2 => nil
```

Conversely, on the same machine, a few seconds later it works via commandline cURL:

```
james@laptop:~/fashism$ curl -I "http://us.asos.com/NW3/NW3-Highgate-Seersucker-Pinafore-Dress/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=1988231&cid=8799&sh=0&pge=0&pgesize=20&sort=-1&clr=Navy%252fivory&r=2"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-RuleEngine-Key: US1.0:ReferrerAnyOrNoneSiteDotUSPreferenceUSOrNone
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 07 May 2012 19:54:03 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: AsosExecutionEngine=ExemptionTimeout=05/07/2012 20:14; expires=Tue, 07-May-2013 19:54:02 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=sd2hw4yu4l4jwmevc3gyan55; path=/; httponly
Set-Cookie: asos=topcatidHitCount=1; expires=Tue, 07-May-2013 19:54:02 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: asos=topcatidHitCount=1&currencyid=1&topcatid=9057&customerguid=b5da62eb44de45eeadd2f36ec90332ca; expires=Tue, 07-May-2013 19:54:02 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: asosbasket=basketitemcount=0&basketitemtotalretailprice=0; expires=Mon, 07-May-2012 20:54:02 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: stop_mobi=yes; path=/

james@laptop:~/fashism$
```

Any ideas? Assistance would be greatly appreciated, even if it's just giving me a direction to go, to find a solution.

Thank you very much!

~James

Answer (score 2):

From my answer on the [Typhoeus github issue](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/issues/153#issuecomment-5702584):

The server requires a number of request headers to be set.

Try:

```
url = "http://us.asos.com/NW3/NW3-Highgate-Seersucker-Pinafore-Dress/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=1988231&cid=8799&sh=0&pge=0&pgesize=20&sort=-1&clr=Navy%252fivory&r=2"
header = {"Accept" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Cache-Control" => "no-cache", "Pragma" => "no-cache", "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19"}
response = Typhoeus::Request.get(url, headers: header, verbose: true, follow_location: true)
```